# Not able to install Windows 10 over Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, freeze, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.4. Right now i am trying to install Windows 10 after removing ubuntu complety. I am using a Lenovo G-50 laptop. I made a bootable pendrive but the problem is when i am getting into boot option by using fn+f12 the installation screen comes but after that everything freezes that is neither my keyboard won't work nor the mouse pad work. Below is the screen where everything freezes .
I had tried changing the ports also but that didn't worked.
[image: Screen where everything freezes]

BIOS setup on my system
[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]
[image: Screen 3]
[image: Screen 4]
[image: Screen 5]
[image: Screen 6]
[image: Screen 7]
[image: Screen 8]

Comment: UEFI will do. It may be a problem with your bootable usb. Try to create bootable usb once again. If that's not working  you may need to download the OS once again.

Comment: @CodeIt Sir the steps which i followed to create a bootable pendrive are - Step 1 - Format pendrive using GParter then loaded os using Woeusb Step 2 - Format pendrive using GParter then loaded os using UNetbootin Tried with two different windows 10 iso file from Microsoft website

Comment: @ShantanuNandan did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I made a bootable pendrive but the problem is when i am getting into boot option by using fn+f12 the installation screen comes but after that everything freezes that is neither my keyboard won't work nor the mouse pad work. Below is the screen where everything freezes

I had the same problem a few years ago.
I found [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/install-windows-10-from-usb) tutorial then, it helped me then.

> How to Clean Install Windows 10 from USB
>   In this post we will see how to clean install Windows 10 using a USB flash drive, on a separate partition. This process can even be used if you want to dual-boot it with another operating system. For this, you will have to first create bootable USB media from ISO for Windows 10. You will also have to create a separate partition, with at least 16 GB space, using the built-in Disk Management tool, if you plan to dual-boot it. This is one of its system requirement.
>
> NOTE: Read this post Install Windows 10 after upgrading first.
>
> Having done this, you will have to set your computer to boot from a USB device. Please be very careful when you change the settings here, lest it make your computer un-bootable.
>
> To do this on my Dell laptop, I have to restart it and keep pressing the F2 key to enter the Boot Options Setup.  Here you will have to change the boot order. If your device uses Secure Boot / UEFI, you will have to change it to Legacy. This is how the default setting looked on my laptop.

[image: bios boot options]

> Use the 4 arrow keys of your keyboard, navigate to the Boot tab and change the settings. Disable Secure Boot, enable Legacy option and set Boot List option to Legacy. Next move USB Storage Device to the first position and set it to be the first device to boot from. After making the changes, the setting on my Dell laptop looked as follows. It may be a bit different in your laptop.

[image: legacy boot]

> Once you have done this, with your USB connected to your laptop, restart the laptop.
>
> Note for Windows 10 users: If you upgrade to Windows 10, the new OS will take the product key and activation details from your earlier OS. These are then saved on Microsoft servers, along with your PC details. If you clean install Windows the first time, you may face activation problems. If you performed an upgrade the first time, activated Windows 10, and then clean installed Windows 10 on the same PC, then there will be no activation issues, as the OS will pull activation details from Microsoft servers. So, if your Windows 10 isn’t activated, we suggest you not perform a clean install the first time. First Upgrade the first time, Activate it and then Clean Install.

[image: Install Windows 10 from USB]

> On restart, your computer will boot from the USB, and display the following screen. If you need to see the larger version of any image, please click on the images.
>
> Install Windows 10 from USB
>
> Choose the Language to install, the Time & Currency format and the Keyboard or Input method, and click on Next. You will see the following screen. Click on Install now.

[image: install Windows 10 from USB 2]

> The setup will start.

[image: install Windows 10 from USB 3]

> You will be presented with the License terms. Accept it and click on Next.

[image: install Windows 10 from USB 5]

> You will be asked, the type of installation you want. Do you want to upgrade your existing Windows installation and keep the files and settings, or do you want to Custom install Windows. Since we want to go in for a fresh or clean install, select Custom Install.

[image: install Windows 10 from USB 6]

> Next you will be asked the Partition where you want to install Windows 10. Select your partition carefully and click Next. If you did not create a partition earlier, this setup wizard also lets you create one now.

[image: > install Windows 10 from USB 7]

> Windows 10 installation will start. It will copy setup files, install features, install updates if any, and finally clean up the residual installation files. Once this is done, your PC will restart.

[image: > install Windows 10 from USB 8]

> On restart, you will see the following screen.

[image: > install Windows 10 from USB 9]

> If you are dual-booting it, you will be greeted with the following screen. If Windows 10 is the only operating system on your computer, you may be taken to the log in screen directly.

[image: > install Windows 10 from USB dual boot]

> Windows 10 will ask you a few basic questions about your preferences, before completing the installation and taking you to the Windows 10 > desktop.

[image: > windows 10]

> Once the installation is completed, remember to reverse the changes in the Boot Option setup

If this dos not help, Just try to install it from ubuntu itself as shown in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1178701/857735) answer:

You can create a Windows bootable USB from Ubuntu through `winusb`

Install it:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
>
> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt install winusb

Create it :

`sudo winusb --format </path/to/windows.iso> <device>`

Use `sudo fdisk -l` to get the right `<device>`

Comment: Winusb or Woeusb ?

Comment: What do you mean? On what part of the answer are you asking?

Comment: @ Moshe Slavin  I followed the link given in the answer but now when i run the command after installing winusb i get message which says sudo: winusb: command not found

Comment: Did you do sudo apt install winusb?

Comment: I used this command to install - sudo apt-get update && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install winusb

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink.  While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless.  Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source.   Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks @Run5k for the helpful feedback i'll make sure to use the 'How to write a good answer' next time! thanks a gain!

Comment: @MosheSlavin, always glad to help, but *"next time"* wasn't exactly what I meant.  Please use the `Edit` function on your current answer to ensure that it meets the Super User criteria.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Run5k i edited it... thanks again for guiding me!

Comment: @Moshe Slavin Thanks finally it worked for me.